# what's causing code ENOENT on npm run build check on github for firebase project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, npm

So for a firebase project I'm working on, I ran `firebase init` in my repo and set up the configurations for the project. One of the configurations was to run `npm run build` upon every Github merge into main and deploy to the site I'm hosting. When I created a PR for my branch (which only includes changes adding in firebase hosting functionality and the aforementioned firebase init changes), Github created a check to see if my PR would work. The check failed, and the failed job was related to `npm run build`, specifically with a ENOENT error.

```
Run npm run build
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/runner/work/Project/Project/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/Project/Project/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-12-03T06_52_44_737Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 254.
```

**Currently my Github repo only has javascript and html files, no actual react pages yet.** I was thinking that because I don't have react files, this could be causing the check to fail, but I don't want to merge until I'm sure this error would be resolved by actually adding react pages.

For ref, my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

If you could offer any further context or explanation I'd really appreciate it. This is my first web hosting project so I'm still unclear on everything.

Comment: Does `package.json` exists on your repo? If not, are you adding that in the PR? It's giving that error because it couldn't find that json file and not because you don't have any 'react files'.

Comment: thanks that fixed it, I accidentally had package.json within a folder and not in the root directory.